# Android layout - AVD and Device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have an Android widget that looks different on the AVD and on a real device.
I can't tell what make the difference and how to fix it...

This is how it looks like on the AVD:
[image: AVD_layout]

This is how it looks like on a device (Motorola XT910, Android version 2.3.6):
[image: device_layout]

This is the layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="bottom|fill_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/buttontxt"
        android:textSize="7sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/widget1label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/widget1txt"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRefresh"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/widget1label"
        android:text="@string/refreshButtonText"
        android:textSize="7sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPrev"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnRefresh"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnRefresh"
        android:layout_marginTop="134dp"
        android:text="@string/prev" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNext"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnPrev"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnPrev"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/next" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSwitch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnNext"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnNext"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/switch_" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView_revenueLabel"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView_revenueLabel"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnPrev"
        android:text="@string/time" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_totalLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_time"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_time3"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="@string/monthly_total"
        android:textSize="8sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_rev3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tv_totalLabel"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView_revenueLabel"
        android:text="@string/default_value"
        android:textSize="8sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_time1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnRefresh"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_time"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView_revenueLabel"
        android:text="@string/default_date"
        android:textSize="8sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_time2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tv_time3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_time1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tv_time1"
        android:maxWidth="60dp"
        android:text="@string/default_date"
        android:textSize="8sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_rev2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_rev1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_rev1"
        android:text="@string/default_value"
        android:textSize="8sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_time3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_time2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_rev2"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView_revenueLabel"
        android:text="@string/default_date"
        android:textSize="8sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_impLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView_revenueLabel"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView_revenueLabel"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnSwitch"
        android:text="@string/imps" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_profitLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnRefresh"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
        android:text="@string/profit" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_profit1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView_profitLabel"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
        android:text="@string/default_value"
        android:textSize="8sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_profit2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_profit1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
        android:text="@string/default_value"
        android:textSize="8sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_profit3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_profit2"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
        android:text="@string/default_value"
        android:textSize="8sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_profitTotal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tv_totalLabel"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_totalLabel"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_profit3"
        android:text="@string/default_value"
        android:textSize="8sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_rev1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView_revenueLabel"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnSwitch"
        android:text="@string/default_value"
        android:textSize="8sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_revenueLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tv_profit1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnSwitch"
        android:text="@string/rev" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_imps3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_imps2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_rev2"
        android:text="@string/default_value"
        android:textSize="8sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_imps2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView_impLabel"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_rev1"
        android:text="@string/default_value"
        android:textSize="8sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_imps1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView_impLabel"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView_impLabel"
        android:text="@string/default_value"
        android:textSize="8sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.
I defined the `minHeight` in the `info.xml`: `android:minHeight="250dp"`

Answer (score 0):

There are certain factors which can be considered for this -

1. Actual screen  size - This can be small,normal , large and x large
2. The density of the screen - LDPI , MDPI , HDPI , XDPI
3. The resolution - 320 *480 , 480 * 800 etc.

The widget can look different in devices which have different characterics.
The best way to find out how your layout appears on the all the devices is through the Graphical layout as given in the picture

-[image]

Comment: I tried to do that but still all of the previews are OK.
http://postimage.org/image/mqv8zpqwb/